# Node Package manager watch command not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, webpack

I try to run npm run watch command after installing frontend dependency in my vue js project. I added scripts section in package.json like below-

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js --disable-host-check",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
```

But i Got this error

webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--hide-modules'
[webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! vue-frontend@1.0.0 development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vue-frontend@1.0.0 development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-02-04T10_14_54_712Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! vue-frontend@1.0.0 watch: `npm run development -- --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vue-frontend@1.0.0 watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue of webpack please try this:

```
npm uninstall webpack-dev-server
npm install webpack-dev-server@2.9.1 --dev
npm run serve
```

Comment: have you run npm install ?

Comment: i have updated my answer. Please try above commands. This can be an issue of webpack.

Comment: my problem is solved after updating node js version. Thank you..